# grub2 not detecting pci-e nvme disk (in GRUB command line) old BIOs motherboard

Tags: boot, grub2, bios, nvme, pcie

I have an old motherboard that doesn't support nvme boot. I've connected nvme disk using a pci-e expansion card.

NVME is detected in windows and Linux when booted up from  old HDD.

Since my motherboard doesn't support nvme boot I installed grub2 in my old hdd to boot nvme using GRUB.

The problem is, GRUB isn't detecting the nvme disk at all. In the grub command line `ls` gives `(hd0,msdos1),(hd0,msdos2),.....(hd0,msdos10)(hd1,msdos1)` (my old hdd partitions  and usb flash disk )

I tried

```
insomd pci
insmod lspci
insmod setpci
insmod pcidump
```

then `ls` but after all that still Nvme isn't listed.

I tried EasyBSD for Windows Boot Manager too but the same problem

Finally I installed my `/boot` partition in old hdd and `/` (and swap ...) in nvme and successfully booted my Ubuntu and Kali.

Now I can install and boot Linux from nvme but for Windows this trick doesn't work because Windows can't have a separate `/boot` on a different partition.

How can I make GRUB detect pcie nvme disk like Linux kernel?

OR

How can I make Windows install its boot files on one partition and other files on a different partition?

OR

Is there any other boot loader that supports both Windows and Linux and pci-e devices (hard disk)?

Comment: Possible similar thread? BIOS boot on NVMe drive with old BIOS and PCIe card
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2415658
 I have seen Windows installs with Boot partition on one drive & c: drive on another drive. Windows boot partition defaults to drive set as default in BIOS, so install to NVMe drive may still put its boot on HDD. But Windows has overwritten Linux partitions as it does not correctly see them, so be sure to have good backups.

Comment: oldfred :  i had done the  same step the topic is saying and have successfully booted linux from nvme as mentioned in thread ,
for windows i tried to install on nvme but windows doesn't accept it for installation also i doubt if windows boot manager (even if could install on separate partion using bcdedit and ...) detect nvme or not (like grub) 
i'd be happy if you tell me how to make windwos boot parttion separate

Comment: No idea, but have seen installs as they overwrote a Linux partition with its Boot partition on a different drive. Best to ask on Windows forum or https://superuser.com/ as this is an Ubuntu question & answer site.

Comment: i tried adding entry too widnnows boot loader to boot windows from nvme but unfortunatlly windows boot loader doesn't detect nvme  too (just like grub).
the only way to to make grub detect nvme (we have to wait for grub to give an update or write a modlue ourself ) 
can't we use linux kernel modlues  in grub ? if it's possible the problem of me and lots of other ppl is solved

Comment: Most NVMe drives need both UEFI & BIOS updates to work with Ubuntu. But using a system that does not directly support in UEFI/BIOS the new NVMe drives is not a frequent problem. Most with older systems just use standard SSDs and even then have to make sure BIOS supports it. My motherboard from 2014 has a M.2 slot, but not NVMe types. NVMe drives were real expensive in 2016 when I built a new system that did support NVMe M.2 drives.